# Loading and posting an external Joomla form view

Tags: ajax, joomla

In Joomla 3.03 I have built a component and a form view for adding to and editing records.  I want to load this form into another entirely separate view where we are writing out the records.

I know I can use jQuery.load() to pull in the form but how can I dynamically load it into place on the separate view and allow it to be completed/validated/posted as if you were on the orginal form view page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new feature of Joomla 3.0 `JLayout`, it enables view reuse inside or accross extensions. For more details, check in docs [Sharing layouts across views or extensions with JLayout](http://docs.joomla.org/Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout)

Comment: Thanks very much for that.  I'm not sure how I create the layout from my other view or if it is possible?

I am editing this file..
components/com_showcase/views/profile/tmpl/default.php

I want it to load this form from a separate view...
components/com_showcase/views/jobs/tmpl/edit.php

Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: just check the link i left, you have explanations where to save what, and how to reuse it

Comment: The answer is good. I am at this point no expert in the new MVC, but the catch is that in order to use JLayout, you also need to implement the new MVC in your component.